# How do I write a loop that concatenates lists by a common value? (Python)

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, concatenation

Consider this 'Big' list, which consists of small lists of two single-string values. The big list can be of any size.

```
q= [["a", "b"],["d", "c"],["c", "g"]]
```

I need to write a loop, which links the last and first letters of 'small' lists.

Therefore this example outputs:

```
['d', 'c', 'g']
```

My code is:

```
arr=[]
i = 0
for k in range(len(q)-1):
    if q[k][1] == q[i+1][0]:
        new = q[i]
        new.append(q[i+1][1])
        print(new)
        arr.append(new)
    else:
        print("no match")
    i+=1

print(arr)
```

it works, but it only checks 1st with 2nd and 2nd with 3rd small list. How can I rewrite it?
I need to write a code that finds all paths of length two in the corresponding string links. That is, it finds the triples of strings (a, e, k) such that there is a link from a to e and a link from e to k.

Comment: It's not clear to me how you would decide what the correct result should be for a larger input. It's also not clear to me exactly what the input specifications are. Are the sub-lists always exactly two elements, each of which is exactly a length-1 string? Or what? And what is the overall *problem that you solve* by producing this output from the input?

Comment: sorry I will update now. It is always two elements, but the number of small lists can vary. The length of a string is always constant. The code must connect every small list by first and last letters. These supposed to be the linkage of URLs, I simplified the example.

Comment: What if there is a cycle? For example, for `[['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['c', 'a']]`, should the result be `['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']`? Or `['b', 'c', 'a', 'b']`? Or `['c', 'a', 'b', 'c']`? Or something else? What if there are multiple chains of the same length, like `[['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['x', 'y'], ['y', 'z']]`?

Comment: In the computer science literature, the problem you describe is a *graph traversal* problem, but not yet one that's fully specified.

Comment: Thank you. It must only link once to create a 3-string array.

Comment: I need to write a program that finds all paths of length
two in the corresponding string links. That is, it finds the triples of strings (a, e, k) such
that there is a link from a to e and a link from e to k.

Comment: Ah. Well that's quite different, then. The only part that's difficult for you is creating the pairs of sublists (in either order), so that you can then assess whether or not they form a valid link. This is solved neatly by `itertools.permutations`, and there are any number of duplicate questions on the site.

Comment: If you have a list like q= [["a", "b"],["d", "c"],["c", "a"]] the result should be like [[d,c,a],[c,a,b]]. Finding all possible triplets. Is this your question?

Comment: Yes, correct. I just need help with rewriting the code.